# Indicating the path correctly in Julia

Tags: julia, filepath

I need to run a file in JULIA. To do so, I type the next command:

```
include("C:\Users\...\...\...\...\Function_Codes\File.jl")
```

The problem is that it does not recognise the backslashes, and I have to change them manually to put the same path with forwarding slashes:

```
include("C:/Users/.../.../.../.../Function_Codes/File.jl")
```

Can I configure JULIA to interpret the path correctly with backslashes? If not, how can I convert the path automatically instead of changing the slashes manually one-by-one

Comment: Use [raw string literals](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#man-raw-string-literals), which don't expand escape sequences like `\uxxxx`

Comment: does it mean just putting 'raw' before the path? So the route would be `include(raw"C:\Users\...\...\...\...\Function_Codes\File.jl")`

Comment: Yes. You can also escape the backslashes instead, so `include("C:\\Users\\...\\...\\...\\...\\Function_Codes\\File.jl")`.

Comment: I also think you can always use `/` because Julia will correctly handle it if you're on Windows?

Comment: What about `joinpath(homedir(), "...", "Function_Codes", "File.jl")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I verified that putting 'raw' before the path works perfectly fine from the comments added to my question. The user @Brian suggested this solution.

The command would be:

```
include(raw"C:\Users\...\...\...\...\Function_Codes\File.jl")
```